# Not sure how to make my function call properly

Tags: javascript, function

I am attempting to call a function from the program, however it only calls if inside a button tag I'm trying to get it to call automatically when the page runs, or call it from inside another function, but it doesn't seem to work.
contents of function not important (I think)

```
<head>
<script>
const x = Number(prompt("enter number"))
function createGridCells() {
        var y = document.getElementsByTagName("p2")[0];
        square = "<div class=\"grid-item\"></div>"
        wall = "<div class=\"grid-space\"></div>"
        let z = ((square + wall))
        a = z.repeat(x-1)
        b = a + square
        c = wall.repeat(x*2 - 1)
        d = b + c
        e = d.repeat(x-1)
        f = e + d
        g = f + square
        y.outerHTML = f
    }
function createGridSize() {
        pixelNum = "45px 5px "
        columnsAndRows = pixelNum.repeat(x-1)
        declaration = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style;
        setProp = declaration.setProperty("grid-template-columns", columnsAndRows + "45px");
        declarationTwo = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style;
        setPropTwo = declarationTwo.setProperty("grid-template-rows", columnsAndRows + "45px");
}
function runMaze(){
            var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            if (randomInt == 1 ){
                moveRight()
            }
            if (randomInt == 2){
                moveLeft()
            }
            if (randomInt == 3){
                moveUp()
            }
            if (randomInt == 4){
                moveDown()
            }
        
    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
createGridCells()
createGridSize()



</script>
<button onclick="createGridCells()">cells</button>
<button onclick="createGridSize()">size</button>
<div class="grid-container">
<p2></p2>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: move the script where you call those functions to the END of body, so that the elements the functions need are present

Comment: Wow, it was that easy. Thanks a bunch, been stuck on this for 2 days now.